# Integrate digital signature (Base64-encoded) into pdf file

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I'm using NakovDocumentSigner API to sign pdf files.
Once the pdf file is signed, I got a Digital signature (Base64-encoded) and a Certification chain (Base64-encoded), I want to convert that to a pdf document containing a visual digital signature ?

Comment: Please refer to the PAdES standard or to ISO-32000-1 and explain where the concept of Base64-encoded digital signatures are discussed. As far as I know, there is no such thing as Base64-encoded digital signatures in PDF. Once a *real* digital signature is applied to a PDF, you can't add extra content to that file without breaking the digital signature. You'll have to elaborate if you want us to understand your question. In its current state, you seem to be asking something that is in violation with the PDF standard.

Comment: Once the pdf file is signed, I got a Digital signature (Base64-encoded) and  a Certification chain (Base64-encoded), I want to convert that to a pdf document containing a visual digital signature ?

Comment: Once the PDF is signed, you can't add an image to the PDF anymore. You certainly can't change the appearance of the digital signature without breaking that signature.

Comment: *Once the pdf file is signed* - That sounds like you take the original PDF, somewhere create a signatrue for it, and now hope to somehow integrate the signature into the PDF. Is that the case?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) first...

Comment: this is exactly the case !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As became clear in comments, the OP *takes the original PDF, somewhere create a signature for it, and now hopes to somehow integrate the signature into the PDF.*

This is unfortunate because it is not how integrated PDF signatures work. To get an impression how they works, please read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) on Information Security. The short version:

> you have to build a new revision of the PDF document which includes a PDF AcroForm signature field whose value is a signature dictionary whose **Contents** entry contains the signature of the whole new revision with the exception of the **Contents** entry value.
>
> [image: sketch]

This should show why a signature of the original PDF cannot be used here.

As you tagged your question [itext](/questions/tagged/itext), you should then read [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software), a whitepaper explaining how to use iText for creating integrated PDF signatures.

With that knowledge you then can check whether or not the *NakovDocumentSigner API* can be used for creating integrated PDF signatures.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helps a lot !
Does the pdf AcroForm supports signature Base64-encoded ?

Comment: *Does the pdf AcroForm supports signature Base64-encoded* - it is of no concern whether or not the signature is Base64 encoded. If it is, one can simply decode it. What does matter is the format of the signature. Is it a PKCS7/CMS signature container? Or what is it?